# WebForms, ASP.NET Validators and JS validation frameworks

Tags: asp.net, webforms, parsley.js

I am a long time webform developer. I am used to using the asp.net validator controls to validate user input.

While I like the fact that asp.net has the potential to validate the input on both the client and server side, I feel that the way the validators render isn't ideal. I'm constantly looking, with envy, at javascript validation libraries (like Parsley.js) and wishing asp.net validators would work like that. For instance, I'd like to be able to change the css class for  fields that fail validation. Or I'd like to hide or display an img based on validation logic.

However, the problem with moving to a library like Parsley.js is I lose server side validation, which for security purposes, is the most important layer.

Is there a way to integration server side validation, with a client side framework? In a way that doesn't require a lot of duplicate effort?

Comment: Have you looked at http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/?

Comment: asp.net mvc melds perfectly with `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`. You should look into those for adding client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net You can always trigger validation by the **validator1.Validate()** method, which will do the server-side comparison. Check **Page.IsValid** to see if server-side validation isn't being performed? I think you can invoke it via **Page.Validate()**.Or the overloaded **Page.Validate(string)** to target one of your validation groups.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx